# grep with regex functionality in linux

Tags: regex, shell

```
$ echo 'HI' | grep '\w*'
HI
$ echo 'HI' | grep '\w+'
$ echo 'HI' | grep '\w{2}'
```

For cases 2 & 3, grep must have returned 'HI', but is returning nothing. Is there something wrong in what I am grepping for?

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong. Did you read the replies you received already? In grep's regex syntax, `\w` matches a literal w, and `+` matches a literal plus sign. (In this case, it's redundant anyway, because grep prints the entire input line if there is a match). You are looking for `echo hi | grep -i '[a-z]'` or if you really insist on using Perl's regex syntax `echo hi | perl -ne 'print if /\w/'`

Comment: GNU `grep` supports options `-G` (BRE: basic regular expressions), `-E` (ERE: extended regular expressions), `-F` (fixed strings, but optionally many of them), and `-P` (Perl regular expressions - though it doesn't say precisely which version of Perl).  If you have GNU `grep` and want Perl-style regular expressions, use `grep -P '^\w{2}$'` or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions in their pure form is precisely what Global Regular Expression Print supports. The `\w` escape was introduced in Perl regular expressions in the late 1980s, almost 20 years after grep was created. The GNU grep suite alludes to a command `pgrep` in its documentation, but you are probably better off learning the differences, and learning to use traditional regexes with grep.

Comment: just add a -P switch to turn on PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)